# MongoDB aggregation: Group all records into a single result

Tags: mongodb, database

In a mongodb aggregation call, how do I use the $group operator to group all documents in the pipeline into a single result?

Let's say I have a collection of records that look like this:

```
{
    user_id: 234,
    signup_date: 2013-06-27
}
```

I want to use the aggregate function to query the database for a list of users who signed up in a given date range, and return it as a list. I'd like a result that looks like this:

```
{
    users: [234, 235, 236]
}
```

My query looks something like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([

    { $match: {
        signup_date: {
            $gte: date_begin_variable,
            $lt: date_end_variable
    }},
```

So far, so good. I now have a subset of records, all of which have a signup date in the desired range. But here's where I get into trouble. Now I want to group ALL those records into a single result containing a list of all the IDs. But I don't know how to do that using $group.

```
    { $group: {
        _id: null
        users: { $addToSet: user_id }
    }}

])
```

When I tried _id: null, I got back an empty list of user IDs.

I could just return the desired set of records using find(), and then just process the IDs into a list manually, but doing it using aggregate() seems cleaner. Am I wrong about that? What would be the best way to accomplish what I'm describing, either using aggregate or not?

Comment: _id: null is correct, how "doesn't it work"? (Saying "it doesn't work" is not very good question asking, as we've no idea what you expect to have as output, and what you got)

Comment: whats the output you currently get?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. When I tried _id: null, I got an empty list of user IDs. If that is the correct way to approach this, I'll go back and check my code.

Comment: Try this instead: `users: { $addToSet: '$user_id' }`

Comment: I figured it out. Earlier in my pipeline I had added another `$group` operation, such that the `user_id` field was renamed to `_id`, so when I did `$addToSet: user_id`, it failed because there was no longer a field called `user_id`. I changed that line to `$addToSet: _id` and it works perfectly now.

Thank you for the hint that `_id: null` is the correct way to do this. That allowed me to stop focusing on that part and find what was actually wrong with my code.

Answer (score 12):

Try this query:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      signup_date: {
        $gte: date_begin_variable,
        $lt: date_end_variable
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      users: {
        $addToSet: "$user_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```